# Mock Google Directory Admin API

Tags: python-2.7, unit-testing, mocking

I have a code snipped that retrieves lists of users from google domain. I'm  trying to write a unittest to return the list of users. But I do not want to query googleapi server to return the users list for the unittest. How do I mock http? Kindly keep in mind that google apiclient wraps the api post request.

An answer that also gives insight into mocking the build service object would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by creating an API key for the project i'm working on, in cloud console.

I created a file http_response.json and copied a sample of the response i'm expecting. 
I used the following snippet:

```
import unittest
from apiclient.discovery import build
from apiclient.http import HttpMock
import original_file
from apiclient.discovery import build

class TestAdmin(unittest.TestCase):
  def setUp(self):
    server_response =  'Blah Blah Blah' # sample server response
    with open('http_response.json','w') as response_file:
      json.dump(server_response, response_file)

  def test_admin(self):
    http = HttpMock('http_response.json', {'status': '200'})
    api_key = 'api key created on google cloud'
    service_object = build('admin', 'directory_v1', http=http, developerKey=api_key)

    # The call to build should be made to a method 
    # in the original  class that implements the build service 

    request = service_object.users().list(customer='my_customer', maxResults=1, orderBy='email',query='/')
    http = HttpMock('allusers.json', {'status': '200'})
    response = request.execute(http=http)
    self.assertEquals(response, server_response)     

  def tearDown(self):
    # delete the temporary file created
    try:
      os.remove(self.user_response)
    except OSError:
      pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
  unittest.main()
```

I typed this out. There may be typos :)